# Wordpress - Hide posts in admin from user who did not write them

Tags: posts

Working on a site and the user only uses two roles. Admin and Author. He has hundreds of authors writing on his blog and wants the ability to hide all Posts under the Posts section of the admin panel that the current logged in author did not write.

Basically when an author logs in he wants them to only be able to SEE their own posts and not everyone else.

It's a competition blog and he doesn't' want them to easily be able to see the total number of posts written by someone else.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm sure there is a hook I can throw in my functions.php file that will hide this, but no look in the last 3 hours of googleling.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand correctly then this could be what your looking for  ["Show only Current Author Posts In Wp-admin"](http://wordpressapi.com/2011/04/10/show-only-current-authors-post-in-wordpress-admin-panel/) it seems to fill your requirements